# Jquery Forward button

Tags: jquery

How to make jQuery in browser link which works as forward button?

**UPDATE :**

So finally this worked for me.

jQuery Code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.back').click(function(){
        parent.history.back();
        return false;
    });
    $('a.forward').click(function(){
        parent.history.forward();
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML Code

```
<a class="back" href="javascript:void()"> Go back </a>
<a class="forward" href="javascript:void()"> Go Forward </a>
```

Comment: this is not a forum. post a complete question

Comment: Have you tried with `parent.history.forward();` for forward?

Comment: Why I got so many downvotes?

Answer (score 4):

This javascript will work,

```
history.go(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Works the same like back, but instead you write forward.

```
parent.history.forward();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the forward() method

```
   window.history.forward();
```

use go() for jump forward to `n` pages by passing `n`

```
window.history.go(1);
```

[Traveling through history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)